# css heading vertical space

Tags: css, html-heading

I'm trying to use CSS/margin-top to add some extra vertical space before H3 headings, but it has absolutely no effect.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.  The relevant CSS is the following:

```
h3{
  color:blue;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:24px <!-- Add vertical space: -->
}
```

The URL of the document is as follows: http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I just went onto the website, opened debugging chrome tools, found an H3 header, deleted `<!-- Add vertical space: -->` from the H3 css, and it worked perfectly... Not sure what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS `margin-top` rule is not being used because CSS comment structure is different. `<!-- some comment-->` is considered as invalid value for the rule. Use the below instead.

```
h3{
  color:blue;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:24px;/*Add vertical space*/
}
```

Also, always remember to add a semi-colon at the end as **mauzy_broadway** has pointed out.

Comment: Technically, the construct `<!-- ... --->` makes the value in a declaration invalid, and by [CSS error handling rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors), browsers must ignore the *declaration* (for `margin-top`), not the entire rule (for `h3`).

Comment: Agreed @JukkaK.Korpela. As long as the semi-colon was present at the end, the `margin-top` would (or should) have also worked. But without it, the comment part is also considered as a part of the value :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working it's because you're using an HTML comment instead of a CSS one, that's like `/* comment here */`.

Remove the comment and the rule should apply just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon after the 24px, the comment is throwing it off.